# LookupError: unknown encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing AES 256 encrypt/decrypt and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

Key : fce4aa4dcf0d2b27fe4ffdafa602c81d1930c410f48ada5c763d4c4052a939eb

IV : c75271d593ca86ca785e3bb25e8d02cb

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\pycrypto.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(a.encrypt(codecs.decode("This bloody encryption engine won't work !", 'c75271d593ca86ca785e3bb25e8d02cb', 'hex_codec')))
LookupError: unknown encoding: c75271d593ca86ca785e3bb25e8d02cb
```

```py
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import codecs

BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS) 
unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]

class AESCipher:
    def __init__( self, key ):
        self.key = key

    def encrypt( self, raw, iv ):
        raw = pad(raw)
        cipher = AES.new( self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return base64.b64encode( cipher.encrypt( raw ) )

    def decrypt( self, enc, iv ):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc ))

a = AESCipher(codecs.decode('fce4aa4dcf0d2b27fe4ffdafa602c81d1930c410f48ada5c763d4c4052a939eb', 'hex_codec'))
print(a.encrypt(codecs.decode("This bloody encryption engine won't work !", 'c75271d593ca86ca785e3bb25e8d02cb', 'hex_codec')))

b = AESCipher(codecs.decode('fce4aa4dcf0d2b27fe4ffdafa602c81d1930c410f48ada5c763d4c4052a939eb', 'hex_codec'))
print(b.decrypt(codecs.decode('44FsQIcqM412+YXZBwwoQSCz2uB9QPQMXJ410Xpw1f/M5RTRS7N6yfziAGq/Fd/E', 'c75271d593ca86ca785e3bb25e8d02cb', 'hex_codec')))
```

Comment: The second parameter of `codecs.decode` is character encoding (such as utf8).

Comment: It appears you are trying to convert an ascii string containing hex notation to bytes. If so, look at `binascii.unhexlify()`. There is no *hex codec* in Python 3.

Comment: @BoarGules The 1st and 3rd hex_codec lines [actually work](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms), but `bytes.fromhex()` is a more direct way to do it in Python 3. Not really sure of the goal of the 2nd and 4th hex_codec lines, but it is used completely incorrectly. The OP might want something like `"This ....".encode()` to get a Unicode string to bytes but it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html), `codecs.decode()` takes the following arguments:

> codecs.decode(obj, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')

In your case, you're passing `c75271d593ca86ca785e3bb25e8d02cb` as the encoding, hence the error.